# how to use External object in S DOC as related list

Tags: document

We are new to SDOC, we are trying to add the external object as related list in the SDOC template editor.
but we are getting the below eror,

**"No such column 'createdDate' on entity 'Orders__x'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
Error is in expression '{!initStep2}' in component  in page sdoc:sdcreate2: (SDOC)

An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been notified. (SDOC)
 "**

please help us.

Thanks 
Manikandan m